# Is it possible to use channels and buffers (java.nio) to read/write types of objects I created from/to a file?

Tags: java

I would like to know if it is possible to use channels and buffers (from java.nio) to read/write types of objects I created from/to a file ?

For example, here is a code sample (not using "finally" or even better try-with-ressources neither closing files because it's not part of a code, just an example to illustrate why I am asking this question).

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

FileInputStream fis;
BufferedInputStream bis;
FileChannel fc;

try {
  fis = new FileInputStream(new File("test.txt"));
  bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
  //initializing timer
  long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
  //reading
  while(bis.read() != -1);
  //execution time
  System.out.println("Execution time with a conventionnal buffer (BufferedInputStream) : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));

  //again
  fis = new FileInputStream(new File("test.txt"));
  //but we catch the channel
  fc = fis.getChannel();
  //from that we deduce the size
  int size = (int)fc.size();
  //We create a buffer corresponding to the size of the file
  ByteBuffer bBuff = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);

  //initializing the timer
  time = System.currentTimeMillis();
  //starting reading
  fc.read(bBuff);
  //preparing reading calling flip
  bBuff.flip();
  //printing execution time
  System.out.println("Execution time with a new buffer (java.nio Buffer) : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

When I execute this code (test.txt is a 4 Mo file), I can see that the execution time is about 10 times faster with the second method than with the first one.
In this exemple, it is done with a byte buffer, but you can do it with any kind of primitive types (IntBuffer, CharBuffer, ...);

Is it also possible to use this second method (using java.nio Buffer) with a type of Objects I created ? Or should I use the first method (using BufferedInoutStream) with it like :

```
 ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                             new BufferedInputStream(
                                 new FileInputStream(
                                     new File("test.txt"))));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your benchmark is invalid, as it only tests a primed cache in the second case. Try it with two different files, or in the other order. You won't get the same results.
2. In any case your tests are not even remotely comparable. What you should be timing in the first case is `bis.read(byte[])` into the same size buffer as in the second case.

When you run valid tests, you will find there is little if any difference, and therefore no motivation for your question. Use a `BufferedInputStream` as per your first example.